Can I put .nvmrc in common\config\rush so that it can be read globally?
Configure .nvmrc in the root directory, and fnm works normally.
But every time I cd to the subproject, fnm fails to read .nvmrc correctly.
Can I put .nvmrc in common\config\rush so that it can be read globally?
In addition, what bothers me is that every time I install a subproject dependency, I have to switch to the subproject to install the dependency. Can the rush add command be enhanced so that it can be executed in the root directory, just like
pnpm --filter, the corresponding rush can rush add --to
